# html file urls is not accessible in django

Tags: python, django, django-urls

register.html is not accessible on 'register/' url

tried changing  url to '' and  webpage is accessible but not on 'register/'

projects urls.py

```
 from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/',include('login.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

apps urls.py

```
 from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.indexView, name = "home"),
    path('dashboard/', views.dashboardView, name="dashboard"),
    #path('login/',),
    path('register/',views.registerView, name="register_url"),
    #path('logout/',),
]
```

views.py

```
 from django.shortcuts import render

def indexView(request):
    return render(request,'index.html')

def dashboardView(request):
    return render(request,'dashboard.html')

def registerView(request):
    return render(request,'register.html')
```

templates/register.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you type **login/** before evry URL pattern of apps urls.py file while testing URL.

or

You should include url mapping of apps urls.py in main urls.py
This might help you.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include


urlpatterns = [
    path('',include('apps.urls')), #put you app name here
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

apps urls.py

```
 from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.indexView, name = "home"),
    path('dashboard/', views.dashboardView, name="dashboard"),

    path('register/',views.registerView, name="register_url"),

]
```

This will work and you can add login/ url mapping inside the apps urls.py.
This type of flow will make it easy to understand .

Comment: sry i mention as apps bt actual that app name is itself login

Comment: if your app name is login then just do this simple edit in  your code, replace 'login/' in main urls.py with just "" bank so url name will not bother you .

Comment: otherwise you have write login before every url name of apps urls.py file.

Comment: the reason itis not accessible on 'register/ because it is accessible on 'login/register/'

Comment: ty bro its working fine :-) hv a nice day ...thank u for answering !!!

Answer (score 1):

Use url_name for URL calling:

```
{% url 'register_url' %}
```

This will directly search for 'register_url' in the project and will return the path.
url_name must be unique so make sure your url_name is uniquely defined.